# fill image background in base of percentage value with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

i need to do a moneybox image and fill it's background color every time changes a percentage value. 
i dont have idea how do it. 
do would like to do it with Jquery or css? 
thank a lot!

[image]

Comment: Have only that "piggy" :D and that line sliced, put them inside a div and change the background-color of that div. On every step you want to change the background-color of that parent div, add a different css class on it (percentage-30, percentage-50, etc) and then style those states from css. Easier and cross-browser.

Comment: it's not possible because the color's div go out from image.
the pig image is not a square , i tried with overflow hidden on image but dont work

Comment: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/nicolaeolariu/LL9JC/1/) a rough ideea, it would help you?

Comment: Aaah, I see, you only want that "piggy" to color out, right? Hmm... Ignore my previous fiddle then.

Comment: Use negative area. Make the piggy image with the inside of the piggy being transparent, then use a white-to-transparent gradient on the background div.